# jQuery HighCharts colour by column

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I notice there is the option colorByPoint, which I have enabled in my chart, but how do I specify a colour for every single point in my data?

Do I have to specify every bit of data sepoerately with it's colour too? If so, how? I've been playing for ages and can't get it right!

Comment: I think I just found it in the Highcharts.setOptions colours! Always happens when I just post a Q up. :)

Comment: However, how can I do this on the fly as I'm populating the chart?

Answer (score 3):

If you know which data point you want to change the colour of, you can change the colour of a data point on the fly by doing something like the following:

```
yourchart.series[yourSeriesIndex].data[yourDataPointIndex].update({
    color: "#123456" //your colour value
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the color for each point as you are populating the series you can do the following:

```
fakeSerioesName.data.push({y : yourYValue,color:yourYColor});
```

Where yourYColor is a hex color.  See example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Dabr3/